# how do i get my database image (byte array) converted to an image in codename one

Tags: codenameone

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: create image failed for the given image data of length: 16182
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:654)   at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:654)
[EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - create image failed for the given image data of length: 16182

Comment: Can you post the code related to this exception?

Answer (score 0):

This generally means you created an image with invalid data. You need to narrow down the issue by checking your logic of both storing and reading the file.